# Adding additional CAN interface to Cosmos

Tags: ruby, cosmos

I am looking to extend the existing interface functionality of Cosmos by allowing it to interface with my selected USB-CAN adaptor. I have the adaptor's SDK ready and working in C, just need it to interface it with Ruby. 
My main question is, where should the SDK files be contained of the used libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I decided to just use Ethernet to CAN bridge allowing me to use the TCP/IP interface already provided by Cosmos.